# Trying to share a link to facebook only shares the main url

Tags: php, facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I am new to twitter,facebook etc api's and javascripts.

A similar question might be asked by some one else but please check my question, I guess this question is not a duplicate one.

I am trying to **share a url to facebook**. Here is my code

```
<?php $link="www.google.com"> 
    <script>
        function fbs_click() 
        {
        u=location.href;
        t=document.title;
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
        return false;
        }
        </script>
        <style>
        html .fb_share_button { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block; padding:1px 20px 0 5px; height:15px;  background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right; } html .fb_share_button:hover { color:#fff; url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top right; text-decoration:none; }
        </style> 
        <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php  echo $link;?>" 
        class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" style="text-align:center;"></a>
        </div>
```

But instead of sharing `www.google.com` it shows **main url** such as `www.mysite.com/facebookshare.php` where am i going wrong.

I also tried a simple anchor tag method to share but it disturbs my entire css.
exmaple

```
<a href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= <?php echo $link;?>">
                    <img src = "http://www.mysite.com/FB_2.png"></a>
```

Please help me to get the exact url i wish (www.google.com) to be shared to facebook.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566503/facebook-share-sharer-php-x-facebook-debugger?rq=1
the sharer part of fb is no longer supported by fb you have to use the feed dialog part of javascript api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
also make sure your og meta tags contain the correct information http://ogp.me/ that could be your problem